# Put in order XAML code

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio we have automatic code ordination when a the current block or sentence is finished/closed. The white spaces are adjusted, the curly braces are aligned, etc. Is there something like that in XAML?

Comment: I could've sworn Visual Studio does this for everything. That said, its idea of what reformatting to do for which language can change between languages. (It generally touches indentation in HTML et al. less.) Or maybe it's ReSharper that does it.

Comment: Check your preferences. There are formatting options in there on a general and per-language basis.

Comment: Try the VS2013 RC, there are alot of improvements for xaml editor

Comment: Try CTRL + K +D, which will "beautify" your code. This should work mostly in XAML too, but sometimes it doesn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for XAML as well, at least if I understand your question correctly.

You can change the settings for how the code is aligned when you go to Tools -> Text Editor -> XAML and you'll see a couple of formatting and spacing options to finetune your code appearance.

Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>) and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> will automatically adjust your code. (If you want to look up the combination to format the document go to Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard and look for "Edit.FormatDocument".)

Comment: I'm not sure that `Ctrl-K` and `Ctrl-D` is equal for all installations. Could you also add the name of that function so that others can find it by that name if the keys don't work? (also, a formatting tip, you can use `<kbd>` to create buttons)